# XNA Elapsed time doesn't update

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to implement a simple counter in my XNA game. Thought this would be simple enough. I have the following code:

```
    elapsed = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        timer -= (int)elapsed;

        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            timer = 10;   //Reset Timer
        }
```

But elapsed never changes from 0.0. Am I missing something obvious here? I suspect I am. I have gameTime declared at the top and initialised as usual.

As asked, here is a bit more code:

public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
  {

```
private GameTime zombieTime; 



    public Game1()
    {
        zombieTime = new GameTime();
        // Other (unrelated) stuff here
    }



    protected void AddZombie()
    {
        elapsed = zombieTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        timer -= (int)elapsed;

        if (timer <= 0)
        {
            timer = 10;   //Reset Timer
            Zombie zombie = new Zombie(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, random);
            zombie.LoadContent(this.Content, "ZombieSprites/ZombieLeft1");
            zombies.Insert(0, zombie);
        }
     }

    protected void Update()
    {
        AddZombie();
        // Other game update stuff here
    }
}
```

I am sorry, I believed the original code snippet would have been enough. I read some pages online where people posted examples of a timer and used the method I have used above. I understand some of the comments made here about the update going fast enough so that elapsed time will always be 0.

Comment: You've got that code... where? What's going to make it execute?

Comment: The code is within the update method. It is run on every update.

Comment: it looks like something isn't calling start on your elapsed time - can we see a little more code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not using the correct GameTime. zombieTime is never updated by anything so it will always be zero'd out. The GameTime you want to use is passed into the Update() function already for you.

The correct way to do it would be like this:

```
protected void AddZombie(GameTime gameTime)
{
    float elapsed = gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    timer -= (int)elapsed;

    if (timer <= 0)
    {
        timer = 10;   //Reset Timer
        // Rest of stuff goes here
    }
}

protected void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    AddZombie(gameTime);
}
```

Comment: Duhhh... Makes sense. Thank you so much! :) And also to everyone else who helped

Answer (score 2):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime_members.aspx

Elapsed game time is the time since the LAST update. TOTAL game time in the cumulative game time...

So, unless you're doing a lot of work you're not showing, you're gonna be taking no time at all to update, so a value of 0 is quite sensible

try shoving a sleep statement in there and see if elapsed time goes up.